# lcdui v/s lwuit

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lcdui, j2mepolish, cldc

I want to create j2me screens for an application. I am new to j2me and wnat to know if i should opt for lcdui or lwuit. I read that lwuit will be supported only in CLDC 1.1 mobiles. I would like to know the list of CLDC 1.0 mobiles. From what I have done with lcdui coding, I think there are many limitations. One of the limitation is that a textbox and a list together cannot be put inside a form. I will need screens where a textbox may be put with a list.

Any j2me professionals, please five suggestions on whether i should choose lcdui or lwuit. And the practical difficulties you faced with each approach.

Thanks

Comment: I've never used LWUIT myself because I basically prefer to code everything myself, but you should definitely go with LWUIT - (unless you feel like coding your own GUI framework).
LCDUI is very device dependent. It'll look different on each device.
MIDP2.0 CLDC1.1 covers enough phones in my opinion. Very few people use CLDC1.0 phones anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use LWUIT. Because you can create an application with good UI by using LWUIT.
you significantly reduce the JAR file size by using the .RES theme for the application design.

As far as i understood, you want to put a Textbox and List inside a form rite? it is very well possible in LWUIT.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use LWUIT with CLDC 1.0 devices as well. There are lot of CLDC 1.0 devices as well that you can search for each manufacturer and the build will work automatically with CLDC 1.1. Also there is no restriction in LWUIT to be used only with CLDC 1.1. UI tweaking is also i little easier in lwuit i would say.